# Flash - recording from user's webcam

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flv, webcam

I've seen a few sites that have a flash app which takes video from the users webcam and manipulates it.  One example is the flash barcode reader http://www.renaun.com/flex2/BarcodeReader/BarcodeReader.html .

I want users to be able to submit 10-15 second clips which I can save to my server and then play back later via flash again.

Can you link to some example projects for this, or tell me what sections of which manuals I should be looking at?

-Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several articles with sample code for this on adobes site. I would recommend you to go through this tutorial as it will guide you through all the necessary steps along with sample code:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/webcam_motion.html

Answer (score 8):

Try the [Red5 RTMP server](http://osflash.org/red5) (Java) and [Red5-Recorder](http://www.red5-recorder.com/) for recording and playback. Demo here: http://www.red5-recorder.com/demo.php

(Both free)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without any flash servers or Red5. Check on the net for some flash and action script books, because on the forums or google you can't find good tutorials about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Adobe Flash Media Interactive Server 3](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediainteractive/) . Just download it and take a look at "sample_guestbook" sample application.